# Java+Selenium: Grouping Methods by Instance Using @Factory

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm having an issue getting methods to run in the correct order using Java+Selenium for some automation.  I've tried the suggestions made in some of the posts I've found on here but none seem to work for me.

I need it to run all of the methods in the order I've written them to run for one instance before proceeding to the next.

In the first instance it runs all the methods but in the wrong order and in the subsequent instances it executes the 1st method for each instance, then the 2nd method for each instance instead of running each method before proceeding to the next instance.

I've attempted to use priority annotations on the test methods to resolve but that causes the entire suite to error out and not run at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Below is my testng.xml, @Factory code, and the code for the class I'm calling.

XML

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="QA Functionality Suite">
<parameter name="environment" value="QA"/>
<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
    <test name="Setup"> 
        <classes>
            <class name = "masterPack.Base" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="AppTest" group-by-instances="true" preserve-order="true">   
        <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="QA"/>
        </run>
        </groups>   
        <classes>
            <class name = "appPack.AppFactory" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Factory Class **Updated to relflect sample shown in provided link.

```
public class AppFactory{

    @Factory
    public Object[] AppFactory() {      
        return new Object[] {new RunApp("Utah","84001","planname",1),new RunApp("Texas","73301","planname",2),new RunApp("Alabama","36006","planname",3),
                new RunApp("California","90001","planname",1),new RunApp("Massachusetts","01001","planname",2),new RunApp("New York","10001","planname",3),
                new RunApp("North Carolina","27006","planname",1),new RunApp("Michigan","48001","planname",2),new RunApp("Virginia","20101","planname",3),
                new RunApp("Colorado","80002","planname",1),new RunApp("Idaho","83201","planname",2),new RunApp("Ohio","43001","planname",3),
                new RunApp("Florida","32003","planname",1)};
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class RunApp extends masterPack.Base{

    //Plan information variables
    public String zip;
    public String state;
    public String stateCode;
    public String planName;
    public String planCode;
    public Integer cvrNum;

    public RunApp(String st, String z, String plan, int cvr){
        //Sets variable for test
    }

    @Test(groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void startApp(){     
        //Starts application
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"startApp"},groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void planPage(){
        //Verifies the correct page has been landed on
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"planPage"},groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void planPageState(){
        //Verifies the page has the correct state association
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"planPage"},groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void planPagePrice(){
        //Verifies the price of items on the page
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"planPage"},groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void planPagePlanDetails(){
        //Verifies details on the page
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"planPage"},groups={"QA","Staging","Live"})
    public void planSelect(){
        //makes a selection on the page
    }
```

Results of the run

[Results of Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm6bV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because of @Factory using @DataProvider annotation

Diference is :

DataProvider: A test method that uses DataProvider will be executed a multiple number of times based on the data provided by the DataProvider. The test method will be executed using the same instance of the test class to which the test method belongs.

Factory: A factory will execute all the test methods present inside a test class using a separate instance of the respective class.

you can go through [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-difference-between-factory-and-dataprovider/)

Comment: I updated my factory class as shown in the page you linked but am still having the same problem.  I tried removing the group-by-instances from the test.xml as i've heard i causes issues with @Factory but that causes the entire thing to run 1 method from each instance before proceeding to the next.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was actually an issue with either the Eclipse IDE or TestNG version.  Running in Eclipse Neon.2 with TestNG 6.10 caused the issue described but running it in Eclipse Mars.2 with TestNG 6.9 it runs as intended